# Multialign in math mode for linear equation system

Tags: tables, equations, align, amsmath

I want to write equation system like this.
[image: Equation System]

I used this code:

```
\begin{tabular}{rcrcrcr}
$k_1$ & $+$ & $2k_2$ & $+$ & $3k_3$ & $=$ & $5$\\
$2k_1$ & $+$ & $9k_2$ & $+$ & $3k_3$ & $=$ & $-1$\\
$k_1$ & $+$ & & & $4k_3$ & $=$& $9$\\
\end{tabular}
```

Is there any simpler way than to write all math-mode with `$...$`?
I want the space more narrow. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{r@{}c@{}r@{}c@{}r@{}c@{}r}
    k_1  &{}+{}& 2k_2 &{}+{}& 3k_3 &{}={}& 5  \\
    2k_1 &{}+{}& 9k_2 &{}+{}& 3k_3 &{}={}& -1 \\
    k_1  &{}+{}&      &     & 4k_3 &{}={}& 9  \\
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you could use the `systeme` package, which is designed to typeset linear systems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}

\sysdelim..\systeme{
  k_1  + 2k_2 + 3k_3 =  5,
  2k_1 + 9k_2 + 3k_3 = -1,
  k_1  +        4k_3 =  9
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Some suggestions: Load the `array` package; define `\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}`; issue the directive `\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}` immediately after starting math mode; and use `\begin{array}{*{3}{rC}r}`. That way, the horizontal spacing will be much improved. :-)